# Safe threading object creation

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Im trying create a tg bot with threading (task) system.

If I declare an instance of a class like this, will I have "race condition"?

**UserMessage.cs**

```
class UserMessage
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsBot { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int ChatId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Main.cs (main thread)**

```
for (int i = 0; i < json["result"].Count(); i++)
                    {
                        UserMessage userMessage = new UserMessage();
                        userMessage.Title = json["result"][i]["message"]["title"].ToString();
                       -----------------------/FILLING OBJECT/--------------------------------
                                      ..............................

                        Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Task_Factory task = new Task_Factory();
                            task.Process_Msg(userMessage);
                        });
                    }
```

The code shows that I need to create N tasks, and one task could not access an instance of the class of another task. Will this work in my case?

Comment: Depending on what `Process_Msg` does, their is seemingly nothing accessing a shared resource. `UserMessage` is created once per task, and it will be safe to update and access individual instances on different threads. However, as with all threading issues, the devil is in the detail and its what not shown that might be a problem.

Comment: What do you think a "race condition" is?